Multiple Selection Quiz on CovertCalculator
I have created a multiple selection quiz with ConvertCalculator. Each multiple selection has a category denoted to it like so:
Question #1 [QC]
Answers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
[QC{OA}, QC{OB}, QC{OC}, QC{OD}, QC{OE}, QC{OF}]
Category A: Answers 1 & 2
Category B: Answers 3 & 4
Category C: Answers 5 & 6
After the user completes the quiz, the results will show at the end of what category their answers fall under. I've gotten that so far.
My problem is that the category result needs to be based on a >=60% equation that I can't quite get figured out, especially since multiple selection on ConvertCalculator is based on a numerical value and not a category value.
I've tried using the following numerical values for the categories, but can't get them to work in every permutation.
Category A: Answers 1 & 2 | Value 1
Category B: Answers 3 & 4 | Value 100
Category C: Answers 5 & 6 | Value 5000
With the results visibility formula being IF(AND (QC >= 1, QC  <100))
Is there a way to do a category value that I'm unaware of?
Any thoughts on using a Datasheet? Would that be more helpful? If so, what formula would I use for the visibility formula for the results?
Is making the numerical values the right way to go and maybe my formula is wrong?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
